# VMWare --> Adding new CD drive --> “Reconfigure virtual machine”

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I am trying to add a new CD/Drive to a VMWare virtual machine. I'm currently doing it via Web UI. I am able to add the drive for mounting an ISO from Content Library. Once the drive is added it give me a notification to "Reconfigure virtual machine" .
Is "Reconfigure virtual machine" is same as Power off and On the VM ?
Note: vSphere Client version 6.8.1.350

Answer (score 0):

When you added the CD you reconfigured the virtual machine. There is nothing else to do for you.

Comment: I think I, missed an important point here, I am adding the CD drive keeping the VM powered ON.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if the VM is on or off. When you change the configuration (and adding a CD drive, or even mounting an image to an existing drive is a configuration change) vSphere brings that message until the reconfiguration is finished. It doesn't mean you have to do anything further.

Comment: When the VM is ON, the addition is not happening and if its OFF, it adds and reconfigure is not required.